# glossaries, glossary-longragged: problem with redefining \glossaryentryfield

Tags: horizontal-alignment, glossaries

I'm encountering a weird problem when changing my list of acronyms from the `long` to the `longragged` style. This is an example for illustration:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,nomain,sanitize={description=false,symbol=false}]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-longragged}
\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{longraggeduc}{%
%  \glossarystyle{long}%  <-- works
  \glossarystyle{longragged}%  <-- does not work
  \renewcommand*\glossaryentryfield[5]{%
    \glstarget{##1}{##2} & \makefirstuc{##4}##3\glspostdescription\space##5\\
  }
}

\newacronym{acr:abc}{ABC}{a b c}
\newacronym{acr:def}{DEF}{d e f}

\begin{document}
\gls{acr:abc} \gls{acr:def}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=longraggeduc,nonumberlist=true]
\end{document}
```

I'm redefining `\glossaryentryfield` because of a special style I need to have, including the capitalization of the first letter of the description. That stuff works with the `long` style, but stops working with the `longragged` style (see the commented line).

LaTeX (`pdflatex`) complains

`! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.`

when processing the `.acr` file generated by `makeglossaries`.

I'm kind of stuck with that problem since I'm unable to identify the reason. Any ideas?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Well, no error then; anyway it does not lead to the expected result, since `&` is the alignment character needed to enter the second column of the `longtable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`longragged` uses `\raggedright`, which redefines `\\` and this means that you can't use `\\` to end a tabular line. Use `\tabularnewline` instead:

```
\\newglossarystyle{longraggeduc}{%
%  \glossarystyle{long}%  <-- works
  \glossarystyle{longragged}%  <-- does not work
  \renewcommand*\glossaryentryfield[5]{%
    \glstarget{##1}{##2} & \makefirstuc{##4}##3\glspostdescription\space##5\tabularnewline
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome - did not expect that one to cause trouble, even though I had a similar problem before.